# How to properly use Selenium with RSpec in GitlabCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

We are trying to add some specs to our project, covering some behaviour thingies. To do so, we use Selenium and locally, it works well.

In GitlabCI (with whom I am not acquainted), the story's a bit different.

Other specs run perfectly, but we reach specs that uses Selenium, it crashes. We had different errors depending on the setup we tried, I'll list them below, with the approach we tried.

In all the following approach, we aim to use a headless chrome driver.

Approach #1 : The Naive

Here, we simply pushed our branch, naively thinking it'll work out of the box using Gemfile. We knew most likely it'd crash because chrome wasn't part of the gitlab-ci.yml configuration.

Result : `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515`

Approach #2 : Educated Naive
So we added `selenium/standalone-chrome:latest` to gitlab-ci.yml, with the same error as a result. We also tried to fix the version instead of `latest`, no change.

Approach #3 : Pointing webdriver toward standalone-chrome service
As we were browsing the internets to find how to deal with this, it appeared we need to tell Selenium & the driver where to look for.
We added `SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"` into env variables of our gitlab-ci.yml and told our webdriver to look for it.
Result: Access refused, `Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:4444 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 4444)`

Alternatively, we also try with a different url ("http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/") but no luck as well:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
   (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.106)
```

We tried also to use `webdrivers` gem, but it seems more and more that this gem will be deprecated soon so we won't build on it, `selenium-driver`'s supposed to do the job well enough.